# Toggle show\hide with jquery but with multiple ids

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show

I have a php page wich generates multiple ULs and a link above each UL, like this

```
<a title="Category one" id="cat-1"> Category one </a>
  <ul id="subcategory-1-ul">
    <li>Subcategory<li/>
    <li>Subcategory</li>
  <ul>

<a title="Category two" id="cat-2"> Category two </a>
  <ul id="subcategory-2-ul">
    <li>Subcategory<li/>
    <li>Subcategory</li>
  <ul>
```

Because there are many subcategories into each main categories I want to hide the ULs and only show them when I click the anchor.

I'm trying to use this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('#toggle-link').click(function() {
            $('#ul-to-hideshow').toggle('slow');
         });
        })
```

This works ok but only for the first UL and an anchor with the same id. I need to modify it somehow to pass the id of each UL or anchor and toggle each UL on and off. I have unique ID for each anchor and its UL.

How do I modify the script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .each or use a common class to hide them;

```
$('.ULCategory').toggle('slow');
```

So your html might then be;

```
<a title="Category one" id="cat-1"> Category one </a>
  <ul class="ULCategory" id="subcategory-1-ul">
    <li>Subcategory<li/>
    <li>Subcategory</li>
  <ul>
```

**edit based on comment**

```
<a title="Category one" id="cat-1"> Category one </a>
  <ul class="cat-1" id="subcategory-1-ul">
    <li>Subcategory<li/>
    <li>Subcategory</li>
  <ul>

$('.cat-1').toggle('slow');
```

Comment: I tried that and it shows or hide all ULs at once, and only if I click the first anchor.
I want to toggle show\hide for each UL by clicking on its anchor.

Comment: Oh ok, then include the id of the <a> inside the class of the ul.  See my edit in a few minutes